# Getting Wordpress posts in a category, ordered by custom field

Tags: sql, wordpress, categories

I am a newbie with WordPress and am trying to modify the standard SQL call for for custom field data posts to limit by category. Here is what I am basing my attempts on, but i just can't figure out how to filter for category 15.

```
$querystr = "SELECT wposts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
        AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'priority'
        AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
        AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND wposts.
    ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value ASC";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use query_posts right before the loop like this :

```
query_posts('meta_key=priority&order=ASC&orderby=meta_value&cat=15&post_type=post&post_status=publish');
```

`meta_key=priority` -> Show posts associated with a certain (priority) custom field.

`order=ASC` -> self explanatory

`orderby=meta_value` -> Sort retrieved posts by the meta_value field

`cat=15` -> Display posts that have this category (and any children of that category), using category id 15

Aditionaly you could use `cat=15,4` to show posts in categoryes 15 and 4 , or `category_name=staff,test` to show posts in staff and test categories .

[More info about using query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) , usualy you can retrive just about any kind of posts building the query using query_posts . Use plain SQL when you can't use query_posts for whatever reasons .

Comment: I like that you broke down each of the args to explain what they do, great answer. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Read the section [Query based on Custom Field and Category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query#Query_based_on_Custom_Field_and_Category) in the WordPress Codex article *Displaying Posts Using a Custom Select Query*. Try googling it next time!

**Edit:** As poelinca pointed out, consider using `query_posts()` if you have no highly customized or complex queries to pull off.